# How to convert ReversedRandomAccessCollection to regular collection

Tags: sorting, mpmediaquery, mpmediaplayercontroller

I've been trying to find a way to sort my resulting MPMediaQuery so that the results are sorted by date.
I've had a lot of difficulty, and then I found the "reversed()" method, but I cannot get the returned data into a format that I can use with the MPMediaPlayer.

My original query:

```
var qryPodcasts = MPMediaQuery()
var titleFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate()
titleFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: "This American Life", forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastTitle, comparisonType: .equalTo)
qryPodcasts.addFilterPredicate(titleFilter)
```

So I tried this:

```
let myItems = qryPodcasts.items?.reversed()
podCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: myItems!) //ERROR HERE
myMP.setQueue(with: podCollection!)
```

Which gave me this error:
`"Cannot convert value of type 'ReversedRandomAccessCollection<[MPMediaItem]>' (aka 'ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<MPMediaItem>>') to expected argument type '[MPMediaItem]'"`

How can I use the results of 'reversed()' in the MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
let myItems = qryPodcasts.items?.reversed()
podCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: Array(myItems)!)
myMP.setQueue(with: podCollection!)
```